# /f was unexpected at this time

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, atom-editor

I got this error when, after installing Node.js, I went to check version of npm in cmd, but I could check the version of node without problem. And now I have this error when I try to install any package for Atom. Can someone please tell me what the heck? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check the windows registry. Head over to regedit -> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor` and check if `EnableExtensions` value is 1. If not, make it 1.

I was also having the same issue and that helped me resolve it.